# SecKeyDecrypt behaves differently on different devices.

Tags: ios, objective-c, rsa

I have a weird problem.

I have some NSData which is RSA encrypted.

Using SecKeyDecrypt I can decrypting the data on an iPhone 6 running iOS 10.3.1.
The same Code however fails to decrypt the data on an
iPhone 5s running iOS 10.2.1 and 10.3.1 and on an iPhone 7 running iOS 10.3.1.

One thing I noticed is, that this behaviour only occurs after the version number changes.

Are there any differences between the devices which could cause such a behaviour ?

Answer (score 2):

It works now that I changed the Keychain Group Name to the Bundle ID of my app in the "Keychain Sharing" Capability.

I have no working theory as to why this resolved the issue and why it only occurred on an iPhone 5 and not on an iPhone 6 but it does...